# regular expression for string of alphanumeric characters except X and x and no leading zeros of maximum length 6

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

How to write regular expression for a string of alphanumeric characters except X, x and no leading zeros of maximum length 6 in java

Comment: Please edit your question to add what you have so far. Thanks!

Comment: [a-wA-Wy-zY-Z0-9]{5}[a-wA-W1-9] may be this work for u

Answer (score 1):

This would do it:

```
^(?i)(?!0|.*[x])[a-z\d]{0,6}$
```

Here's a [**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/mO7rF9/3)

Explanation:

- `^` start of the string
- `(?i)` case-insensitive matching
- `(?!0|.*[x])` don't match if the first character is `0` or if there is an `X` or `x` anywhere
- `[a-z\d]` match an alphanumeric character
- `{0,6}` zero to six times
- `$` end of the string

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
 ^[1-9a-wA-WyzYZ][0-9A-Wa-wyz]{5}$
```

The anchors - `^` and `$` - ensure that a whole string should match. Leading zeros are not allowed due to range of `[1-9]`.